# Convert a RAW image to TIFF in python but keep the metadata

Tags: python, image, image-processing, type-conversion, tiff

I tried converting a raw image to tiff, but I want it to keep the metadata. This is the code I was using earlier:

```
import rawpy, imageio, os
with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
   rgb = raw.postprocess()
imageio.imsave('default.tiff', rgb)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529187/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-image-metadata-alongside-a-tif-with-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1558604/user1558604 not really, what I'm trying to do is make the new converted tiff image have the same metadata as the raw original image.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which metadata you're talking about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11301900/alexander-cécile Device make, device model, focal length, exposure time, F number, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in, and actively using EXIF data, you will almost certainly need `exiftool` installed on your machine - a Perl script by Phil Harvey. That being the case, it is probably easiest to do your image processing with `rawpy` as you are already to produce a TIFF file, then use `exiftool` to copy forward the EXIF data from your raw file.

So, in concrete terms, if your raw file is `Nikon.nef` you would open that and do your `rawpy` image processing to make `Nikon.tif`, then shell out (or use the Python binding) and run:

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile Nikon.nef Nikon.tif
```

which will transfer the EXIF data from your raw file to your TIFF file.